# Understanding Elasticsearch synonym

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

Being very new in Elasticsearch, I'm not sure what's the best way to use synonym.

I have two fields, one is hashtag and another one is name. Hashtag containing names in lower case without whitespace whereas name contains actual name in camel case format.

I want to search based on name in the right format and want to get all matching names along with those docs where it matches hashtag as well.

For example, name contains "Tom Cruise" and hashtag is "tomcruise". I want to search "Tom Cruise" and expected result is it will return all docs which has either name "Tom Cruise" or hashtag "tomcruise".

Here is the way I'm creating this index:

```
PUT /my_index
{
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1, 
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "synonym" : {
                "type" : "synonym",
                "ignore_case" : true,
                "synonyms" : [
                    "tom cruise => tomcruise, tom cruise"
                ]
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "synonym" : {
                "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                "filter" : ["synonym"]
            }
        }
    }
}
}

 PUT /my_index/my_type/_mapping
{
"my_type": {
    "properties": {
        "hashtag": {
            "type":            "string",
            "search_analyzer": "synonym",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "name":{
          "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
}


POST /my_index/my_type/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 1            }}
{ "hashtag": "tomcruise", "name": "abc"    }
{ "index": { "_id": 2            }}
{ "hashtag": "tomhanks", "name": "efg" }
{ "index": { "_id": 3            }}
{ "hashtag": "tomcruise"  , "name": "efg"  }
{ "index": { "_id": 4            }}
{ "hashtag": "news" , "name": "Tom Cruise"}
{ "index": { "_id": 5            }}
{ "hashtag": "celebrity", "name": "Kate Winslet"    }
{ "index": { "_id": 6            }}
{ "hashtag": "celebrity", "name": "Tom Cruise" }
```

When I do analyze, it looks like I get the right tokens: [tomcruise, tom, cruise]

```
GET /my_index/_analyze
{
  "text": "Tom Cruise",
  "analyzer": "synonym"
}
```

Here's how I'm searching:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search?pretty
{
  "query": 
  {
    "multi_match": {
        "query":    "Tom Cruise",
        "fields": [ "hashtag", "name" ]
    }
  }
}
```

- Is this the right way to archive my search requirement?
- What's the best way to search like this on Kibana? I have to use the entire query but what I need to do if I want to just type "Tom Cruise" and want to get the expected result? I tried with "_all" but didn't work.

**Updated:**

After discussing with Russ Cam and with my little knowledge of Elasticsearch, I thought it will be overkill to use synonym for my search requirement. So I changed search analyzer to generate same token and got the same result. Still want to know whether I'm doing it in the right way.

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1, 
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "word_joiner": {
                    "type": "word_delimiter",
                    "catenate_all": true
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "test_analyzer" : {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "word_joiner"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the characteristics of a hashtag? alphanumeric with no spaces? words may be hyphenated, dot separated? Do they have a maximum length? Working back from this will provide input into how you might want to analyze at search time to match on hashtags. Synonyms don't seem like the right tool for this, rather, you need a pattern (or set of patterns) that can take text and generate potentially valid hashtags

Comment: @RussCam thanks for your response. It's very simple, always alphanumeric(mostly only text) with no spaces, no hyphen or punctuation or any special character. For example: ["katewinslet", "tomcruise", "tomhanks", "kimkardasian", "kaynewest", "selenagomez"]. Only thing is, it will be multi-field (list of strings).

Comment: ok, so you need an analyzer that will, given some text: (a) remove spaces, hyphen, punctuation and special characters, (b) lowercase. This analyzer can be used at search time against the hashtag field. `multi_field` means that one field may be analyzed and indexed in different ways (to serve different search purposes), not that a field has multiple values e.g. multiple hashtags in the hashtag field for `my_type`.

Comment: @RussCam Yes, I was thinking synonym might be overkill for what I really want. Any clue for how to build that kind of analyzer without using synonym?

Comment: @RussCam I've updated my post with new search analyzer based on our discussion, would love to hear your feedback. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd be inclined to _start_ with a custom analyzer that uses the `standard` tokenizer, then a `lowercase` token filter and `shingle` token filter with the `token_separator` set to empty string. You can control unigrams and max shingle size if you need to. See how this works for your use case and refine as necessary