# How to include multi_match by default in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Is it possible to change default Kibana search behavior? What I mean is, I want to search "Tom Cruise" which should search using multi_match underneath.

When I just search fo "Tom Cruise", it creates this query:

```
 "query": {
     "query_string": {
       "analyze_wildcard": true,
       "query": "\"Tom Cruise\""
     }   
 }
```

But I want it to behave like:

```
"query": 
  {
    "multi_match": {
        "query":    "Tom Cruise",
        "fields": [ "hashtag", "name" ]
    }
  }
```

To make it simple, when I search "Tom Cruise", it should trigger search analyzer on all these two fields.

Or do I need to create my index in a different way?

Comment: What happens if you remove the double quotes around your query terms? Using double quotes in Kibana, will search for the exact terms.

Comment: @Val Thanks for your response, I tried that but didn't help. Just in case if you are wondering how I'm creating index, here is the ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060966/understanding-elasticsearch-synonym